# How to print elements from an array created with new?

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<ctime>
using namespace std;
int main() {
srand(time(NULL));
while (1) {
    int n;
    bool check_dup = false;
    cout << "Please enter a number: ";
    cin >> n;
    if (n < 2) {
        cout << "Wrong number!!!" << endl;
        break;
    }
    cout << "Size of random array: " << n / 2 << endl;
    int* arr = new int[n / 2];
    cout << "[ Array ]" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < n/2 / n; i++) {
        arr[i] = rand() % n + 1;
        cout << arr[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n/2; i++) {
        for (int j = i+1; j < n/2; j++) {
            if (arr[i] == arr[j])
                check_dup = true;
        }
    }
    if (check_dup) cout << "Duplicates found" << endl;
    else cout << "Duplicates not found" << endl;
    delete[] arr;
  }
   return 0;

 }
```

[image]
After inputting n, we dynamically allocated an n / 2 size array and then stored a random number. And when I run it, the rest works fine, but it only outputs the arr value. Where is wrong?

Comment: `i < n/2 / n` ?

Comment: oh thanks 
However, when modified to n / 2, the address value is output, not the random number.

Comment: Maybe add a space or newline between your numbers so you can see them clearly